# Programming against an ACT! database

Tags: database, api, act

Does anyone know the database format for ACT. I am trying to write an exporter for ACT! I've looked for libraries and can't find any obvious ones that will help me interact with the CRM system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have not programmed with act since act 2000 (i did the programming in 2004, though). i used their ACTOLE.APPOBJECT com object to program it from delphi 2000. i had a com programming pdf at one pointer. perhaps its still available from the act people.

-don

Answer (score 0):

Just for anyone coming across this, to Export data from Sage ACT!, you can use the [ACTReader](http://kb.sagesoftwareonline.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/17538/~/what-is-the-act!-reader-utility) utility that comes with ACT to directly access the SQL Server database. This tool creates a read-only sql user account that you can use to open the database in SQL Server Management Studio to look around, or otherwise use in a db connection to query ACT! data like you would any other database.

It's only once you want to Import into ACT! that you need to use the .NET api (btw you don't need to download the "SDK" from Sage. Its mostly sparse and not particularly helpful documentation, all the actual .dll files you need to code for the .NET api were installed with ACT!).

Comment: Sample code on importing to ACT!: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2606910/act-by-sage-integration-with-asp-net

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this will looking for something else and thought I'd add something a bit more conclusive...

Exporting from Act! versions 7/8 or later can be done via a number of methods:
OLEDB, ODBC (or direct access to SQL with the later versions), SDK, WebAPI, or a number of third-party tools that already pull everything to Excel (or other formats).

I did a presentation of the various options some time ago, posted here: 
https://blog.glcomputing.com.au/2009/07/connecting-to-act-by-sage-data.html